# File in use while perform delete even though stream is closed

Tags: java, jsf

I try to delete my file in directory but fail in jsf managed bean.
Can someone please help ? Thank a lot.

Below is my xhmtl code

```
#{incomingCheckList.checkImage(result.imageURL)}

<p:graphicImage value="#{incomingCheckList.image}" stream="false" styleClass="checkListImageSize"/>

#{incomingCheckList.closeStream()}
```

Below is my managed Bean code

```
private StreamedContent image;
public void checkImage(String attachment) throws IOException {


    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(attachment));

    image = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File(attachment)));

}

public void closeStream() throws IOException {
    try {
        image.getStream().close();
        System.out.println("closed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }

}
```

Below is my delete code

```
for (int i = 0; i < allCheckList.size(); i++) {
            if (allCheckList.get(i).isDeleteOrNot()) {

                File file = new File(fileUploadPath + "/incomingCheckList/" + allCheckList.get(i).getComponentPhoto());


                try {
                    Files.delete(file.toPath());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

After i read and close the stream, I try to delete my image file. 
but it show me error said that not able to delete the image file because of the resources is in use.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `public void checkImage(String attachment)` method you do the following:

1. You create a new `FileInputStream` out of a new `File`
2. You then proceed to completely forget it ever existed.
3. Then you create ***a whole new*** `FileInputStream` out of a new `File`, which you pass to `new DefaultStreamedContent()` to create your image.

Then, later, you only close the input stream of that image.

The first `FileInputStream` that you created will only close when it gets garbage-collected, and there are no guarantees as to *when* or even *if* that will happen.

The fact that you made this mistake means that you received no warning about the unused local variable `in`.  Which in turn means that you are trying to program without warnings enabled.  Don't do that.  You are not going to go very far unless you first enable as many warnings as possible, and then make sure that your code never generates any warnings.

Comment: Oh..i see...Finally it can delete successfully~!!!.thanks for your advise for my mistake... appreciate..

Comment: In between,
"Which in turn means that you are trying to program without warnings enabled."
would you mind to share with me how to enable warning ?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using netbeans 8.1

Comment: Okay, netbeans is a bit poor in that respect.  Here is some information: (use Source -> Inspect, and FindBugs) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778984/how-to-display-all-java-compiler-warnings-in-a-project-using-netbeans